# Distributing Value into 3 Dropdown

Tags: php, oracle

So i have an assignment to input values but there is a limit so that when user cant go over the certain limit given. the problem is, i dont know how to distribute the number into three input markups so that the sum of those 3 inputs doesnt go over the limit and it has to be in real time too.

```
<?php
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)){

$qtyAvailable = $row['QTY_REQUIRED'] - $row['QTY_CNCED'];   
       echo '<input class="form-control" name="quantityToCutCnc" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="CNC">';
       echo '<input class="form-control" name="quantityToCutScator" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="Scator">';
       echo '<input class="form-control" name="quantityToCutManual" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="Manual">';
```

}
?>

lets say the $qtyAvailable is 10, and when user slide the first input into number 10, in real time they cant increase the number in input 2 and 3.

thanks in advance for your guys help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery.data( document.body, "selector", number );
```

and

```
$( "#yourinputselector" ).bind( "click", function() {
//get data + quantity analysis
alert( "You have x amount left" ); //or something of the like
});
```

see [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

you should be able to use something akin to this to do an evaluation on quantity onclick